# How to set error message using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

So I have been working quite a while with protractor and I have found out that I am having issue having error message etc. if I don't find a element by 60 sec then I will just get a thrown error for timeout. Which is not a really good way to see whats the issue actually and I am here asking you guys how I am able to put my own error message etc that this specific element has not been found or something like that.

I have coded something like this.

Test case class:

```
const userData = require("../globalContent.json");
const Page = require("../objects/ikeaProductPage.obj");


describe("Product page", function () {

    ikeaPage = new Page();

    for (let [link, amount] of Object.entries(userData[browser.baseUrl])) {
        // The Ikea page is accessible by the specified URL
        it(`Is defined by the URL: ${link}`,
            async function() {
                await Page.navigateDesktop(`${link}`);
            });

        // page has a quantity label and it can be filled out with user data
        it("Has a label quantity that can receive user data",
            async function() {
                await Page.fillFormWithUserData(`${amount}`);
            });

        // Details page allows the user to add to cart
        it("Enables resolution of added to cart",
            async function() {
                await Page.hasAddToShoppingCart();
            });

        // Details page allows the user to proceed to the next stage when page has been resolved
        it("Allows the user to proceed to the next stage of add to cart",
            async function() {
                await Page.hasAddedToBag();
                await browser.sleep(1000);
            });
    }
});
```

Object class:

```
const utils = require("../utils/utils");
const Specs = require("../specs/ProductPage.specs");

module.exports = class Page {

    constructor() {
        const _fields = {
            amountInput: Specs.productAmount
        };

        const _formButtons = {
            addToCart: ikeaSpecs.addToCart
        };

        const _productFrame = {
            cartIcon: ikeaSpecs.cartIcon,
            addedToCartIcon: Specs.addedToCart,
        };

        this.getFields = function() {
            return _fields;
        };
        this.getFormButtons = function() {
            return _formButtons;
        };
        this.getFrame = function() {
            return _productFrame;
        };
    }

    getForm() {

        return {
            fields: this.getFields(),
            buttons: this.getFormButtons(),
        };
    }

    getPageFrame() {
        return {
            buttons: {
                iconFrames: this.getFrame()
            }
        };
    }


    //Navigate for Desktop
    async navigateDesktop(URL) {
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        await browser.manage().window().maximize();
        await browser.get(URL);
    }

    //Fill qty from globalContent.json
    async fillFormWithUserData(amountQuantity) {
        const formFields = this.getForm().fields.amountInput;
        await formFields.clear();
        await utils.sendKeys(formFields, amountQuantity);
    }

    //Check if we can add to shopping cart
    async hasAddToShoppingCart() {
        const formButton = this.getForm().buttons.addToCart;
        await utils.elementToBeClickable(formButton);
        await utils.click(formButton);
    }

    //Check if the product has been added
    async hasAddedToBag() {
        const frameCartIcon = this.getPageFrame().buttons.iconFrames.cartIcon;
        const frameAddedToCart = this.getPageFrame().buttons.iconFrames.addedToCartIcon;
        await utils.presenceOf(frameCartIcon);
        await utils.elementToBeClickable(frameAddedToCart);
    }

};
```

utils:

```
const utils = function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    this.presenceOf = function (params) {
        return browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(params));
    };

    this.elementToBeClickable = function (params) {
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(params));
    };

    this.sendKeys = function (params, userData) {
        return params.sendKeys(userData);
    };

    this.click = function (params) {
        return browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", params.getWebElement());
    };

    this.switch = function (params) {
        return browser.switchTo().frame(params.getWebElement());
    };

    this.switchDefault = function () {
        return browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
    };
};

module.exports = new utils();
```

and I wonder etc how I can set any more correctly errors instead of just timeouts?

Comment: what is `utils` in your code? a package from internet, or something you wrote?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Wops! Will add it right away

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Just added :)

Comment: great, then it's easy. The response is coming shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `browser.wait` under the hood, then you want to consider using one of it's [parameters](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait). As the page suggests, it takes 3 parameters, and all are useful:

```
browser.wait(
  () => true, // this is your condition, to wait for (until the function returns true)
  timeout, // default value is jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval, but can be any timeout
  optionalMessage // this is what you're looking for
)
```

## updated

So if I use all three it'll look like this

```
this.presenceOf = function (params, message) {
  return browser.wait(
    EC.presenceOf(params),
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL,
    `Element ${params.locator().toString()} is not present. Message: ${message}`
  )
};
```

when you call it, like this

```
await utils.presenceOf(frameCartIcon, 10000, "frame should be populated");
```

and it fails, you'd get this stack

```
      - Failed: Element By(css selector, "some css") is not present. Message: frame should be populated
      Wait timed out after 1002ms
      Wait timed out after 1002ms
          at /Users/spleshakov/Documents/ui-automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2201:17
          at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/spleshakov/Documents/ui-automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
          at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/spleshakov/Documents/ui-automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
          at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/spleshakov/Documents/ui-automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
          at asyncRun (/Users/spleshakov/Documents/ui-automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
          at /Users/spleshakov/Documents/ui-automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
          at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
      From: Task: Element By(css selector, "some css") is not present. Message: frame should be populated
```

Comment: You are my sensei! You have helped me alot and probably just a beginning aswell. I really appreciate it and it was exactly what I was looking for aswell! Really relly apprecaite it Sergey! :) - I do have a question, if I want to use the default timeout in that case, should I not enter anything for 10000 or still need to add a timeout?

Comment: yes, either specify the timeout as `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` or `undefined`. if it was helpful, please accept and upvote

Comment: Just curious, how am I able to do the `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`? as the timeout if it doesn't take too long time for you of course :)

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, and if I'm not mistaken, `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` specified in the config as `defaultTimeoutInterval`. If not, it set to 30 sec. And then it is available as global variable anywhere in the project as (no need to require it). and I updated the answer to indicate how to set the default timeout

Comment: Exactly as I wanted! I assume we need to change `await utils.presenceOf(frameCartIcon, 10000, "frame should be populated");` to `await utils.presenceOf(frameCartIcon, "frame should be populated");` aswell in that case?

Comment: I did realized a small problem, so what happens is that it still return a timeout `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.` on the test that fails but then it gives us our error message on the next test case if you know what I mean? What could cause this if u know ? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211630/discussion-between-sergey-pleshakov-and-protractornewbie).

Comment: Im in and waiting :)